# Question about a query

Tags: sql

```
$sql = "SELECT count(u_id) AS num_replies FROM `replies` WHERE `u_id`='".$uid."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(myqsl_error());
```

Will that return the number of replies a user with id $uid has made? If not, can anyone suggest something that will?

Thx for the help.

Comment: Just remember to sanitize $uid first. :-)

Answer (score 5):

It difficult to answer this question without knowing more about the replies table, but just looking at your query, then yes your query looks like it will.

Answer (score 1):

Please, for the love of the internet, don't built an SQL query yourself. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 0):

`$ssql = "SELECT count(*) AS num_replies FROM replies WHERE u_id = $uid";

$rres = mysql_query($ssql);`

Comment: The GROUP BY clause is unnecessary because the WHERE clause reduces the set that COUNT(*) is dealing with to just the records matching $uid.

Comment: So now your query is the same as his except it's counting * instead of u_id which makes absolutely no difference. I'm not sure why you bothered answering.

Comment: Actually, if u_id is nullable, then it *does* make a difference.

Comment: If it's nullable, then it will be rejected by the WHERE condition.

Answer (score 0):

It will return the number of records in the table with that u_id. Doesn't matter what you put in the paretheses. You don't need any GROUP BY clause.